C# generics - generic interface where implementation must be a curiously recurring template pattern
I've recently learned of the Curiously recurring template pattern, where a generic class MyGeneric<T> is implemented with the implementing class's type as the generic type param:
class Concrete : MyGeneric<Concrete>

I wondered if its possible to define an interface that must only be implemented with this pattern, as in that the chosen type parameter must at the least be covariant with the implementing class's type.
What I mean by this is that I want the interface/class to be defined such as that when an a class X implementing/deriving from the interface/class MyGeneric<T> with a type specification, said type specification must be X or a class covariant with it (perhaps with implicit conversion to/from)
For example:
// should X implement MyGeneric with a specific type, said type must be X itself.
class X : MyGeneric<X> // valid, type param X is covariant with implementing class X
class Z
class Y : MyGeneric<Z> // invalid, type param Z is not covariant with implementing class Y

Some more examples from the original version of this question:
class A : MyGeneric<A>; // valid
class B : MyGeneric<A>; // invalid
class C : IMyGeneric<D>; // maybe valid if we really push it
class D : C;


I feel like there might be some SOLID arguments about why not to do this, but I'm not interested on whether I SHOULD, I'm interested about whether I COULD.
So, is it possible?

I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you asking whether it is possible to design a generic interface with a generic parameter constrained to be the interface itself, like so:  public interface ISomeInterface<TSelf>  where TSelf : ISomeInterface<TSelf>;?  Then yes, you can do it.  In fact this pattern is used extensively in generic math, e.g. INumber<TSelf>.  Does that answer your question?

If that does not answer your question might you please [edit] your question to clarify what you are trying to do?  Thanks!

I feel OP's after something similar to this

@dbc attempted to add more explanation, hopefully it helps explain :)

@IvanPetrov, yes, that's precisely what I was after! I wanted to know if its already a thing

On a base class (rather than interface) you can do in the constructor if (this is not T) throw new Exception("Invalid CRTP");

Yes you can! Why not?
Only you need to add to all your types { } at the end and remove ; after class definitions.
In one point, you are wrong: your class class B is also valid. You can easily see it if you create an instance of it and examine it. It is also found valid if you just look at it logically. For better test, you could add some members to all classes involved, don't forger the member of the type A. Let's see:
class MyGeneric<T> { internal string gen = "generic"; }
interface IMyGeneric<T> { }
class Concrete : MyGeneric<Concrete> { };
class A : MyGeneric<A> { internal string a = "a"; }
class B : MyGeneric<A> { internal string b = "b"; internal A aa = new(); } 

class C : IMyGeneric<D> { } // maybe valid if we really push it
class D : C { }

And you can create the instance of B:
B b = new();

You will see: b.b = "b", b.gen = "generic", b.aa.b = "b", b.aa.gen = "generic". What's wrong here? B is also valid. And interfaces are just fine, they won't make any difference.
Everything which is not forbidden is allowed!

Well, what I want is a way to define a generic interface where B wouldn't be valid... since it specifies the spcific type param for MyGeneric as a class that isn't itself.
see https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/5413

Also, yes, I'm aware of the { } being missing, the code blocks were just meant to be pseudocode to convey the idea

@Tomer Trashman — Missing { } and pseudo-code is not a problem, I still was able to understand what you want and add whatever makes sens. The self-referencing template cases are more funny though, because all the real game starts not when we create types and instances, but when we start using self-referenced parameter types in code. I don't know if you want to dig in it now. What do you think?

@Tomer Trashman — “Well, what I want is a way to define a generic interface where B wouldn't be valid”. It wasn't obvious from your question. I don't think it is possible. Again, using different generic type parameters should not impose such limitations, I don't see any reasons. The problem may start when you implement interfaces in code, but that is a long story.
